Why does my programm immediately input a blank space as Player1's name?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int playernumber();

struct Player
{
    char name[20];
    int score;
};

int main()
{
    int num = playernumber();
    struct Player players[num];
    int i = 1;

    while( i <= num)
    {
        printf("\nWhat's Player%d's name: ", i);
        fgets(players[i].name , 20, stdin);
        players[i].name[strlen(players[i].name) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("%s", players[i].name);
        i++;
    }
}

int playernumber()
{
    int num;
    printf("Welcome! How many players are there? ");
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(num<0 || num>4)
        {
            printf("Too few or too many players, enter a player number again: ");
        }
    }while(num<0 || num>4);
    return num;
}

Whenever entering a valid number of players the initial value of Player1 is set as a blank space. Is it because of my incorrect usage of the fgets function?I am currently still learning the language so I would appreciate any assistance

scanf("%d") does not consume the newline, so the subsequent fgets read nothing but the single newline.

Don't try to understand scanf, and don't try to fix the code to consume the newline.  Just stop using all variants of scanf.  Pass the number of players as a parameter to main (eg, in argv via a command line argument) instead of reading it from the input stream.  If you do want to read it, use fgets for that also.  Overall STOP USING SCANF.

I am with @WilliamPursell but I find this more constructively phrased: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html Also: "scanf is NOT for accepting input, it is for cleanly formatted syntax, if the input syntax is in ANY doubt, use something else" (which I kind of phrased, but surely is a quote from somewhere I currently cannot link).

You not analyzing the result of fgets(). If the input file is empty, players[i].name is undefined. strlen(players[i].name) can be 0 or 1000. So you can write the null byte outside of the buffer.
